# How to add bulk values in column using DB Browser SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have a table that contain two columns. One column "rewords" contain 12186 words. and the other column named "ID" is the column that I newly created so it is empty. I want to add numbers against the rewords column. numbers from 1, 2, 3, to 12186. i tried to use primary key not null operation but it disturbs the order and its sequence becomes unpredictable like 1,2,6,10,7,8,19.... 
If I manually type 1,2,3 in the fields, then it will be too time-consuming and effortful. Following is the screenshot of what I desire. I want that I could have typing from 1 to 12186 in the fields of ID column.

I also tried the following function in the query tab, but it doesn't work and gives error that "near "for": syntax error: for"

```
for(int i = 1; i<=12186; i++){
    UPDATE tbl SET ID = i WHERE index = i;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need  the loop  you can do this with a single query

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET ID =  index 
WHERE index  <= 12186;
```

otherwise if you have not a column index .. you need  an autoincrement value in you id column  ..  you should

You can do it with SQLite Expert Personal 4:

```
1) Select the table and then go to "Design" tab > "Columns" tab.

2) Click select the ID column name, and type INTEGER and Not Null > Ok.

3) Go to "Primary Key" tab in "Desgin tab". 
      Click "Add" and select the column ID. Check the "Autoincrement" box.

4) Click "Apply" on the right bottom part of the window.
```

Comment: near "index": syntax error: UPDATE tbl 
SET ID =  index

Comment: have you a column named  index in your table  ?  ..anyway check better for the code  .. i don't see  sintax error in my code

Comment: no. but I think index is the very first unnamed column counting as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: answer  updated .. seems you need  an autoincrement column  .. (you could also create the table with the auto increment)

Comment: I tried primary key option, but it doesn't follow the order 1,2,3,4,5.... It generates like this: 1, 2, 63, 64, 65, etc...

Comment: seems strange  .. the autoincrement  .. is by 1 normally  .. check selecting order  by id